# Can a person shorten their own life by using the Death Note?

Tags: death-note

I was reading about the rules of the Death Note on [Death Note wiki](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note) and I came across this certain rule...

> A person can shorten his/her own life by using the note.

What does this rule mean?
Does it mean that when Light uses the Death Note, he loses some of his life? I find it unlikely since he would have died quite a while ago.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides the fact that one can trade half his lifespan for improved usage of the Death Note,

> The human who becomes the owner of the Death Note can, in exchange of half his/her remaining life, get the eyeballs of the god of death which will enable him/her to see a human’s name and remaining life span when looking through them.

A user also can write down their own name in the Death Note. This will cause the user to die early due to their own described causes. Of course the rules of the book still apply, meaning that the user's death as written in the note wont take effect if this occurs after his already stated point of death. Therefore, one can shorten his life using the note.

Comment: L does this in the second Death Note Live Action Movie by writing his name and stating that he'll die in his sleep, by doing that he became immune to any other from of death produced from his name being written in any other Death Note, unlike the anime this is how Light is found out to be Kira by L (rather than by N). since the live action movies take a difference cause than the manga or anime i'm not sure if this is cannon

Comment: @Memor-X The C-Killer also does this in the one-shot from Death Note. Not sure if that would be considered canon either. http://i.stack.imgur.com/SwciH.jpg