# Could I kill myself with a Death Note?

Tags: death-note

[image: Death Note pilot page!]

On the bottom left paragraph, it reads:

> You will not die if you write your own name in here, but it's not recommended.

This page is taken from [the pilot chapter of Death Note](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Note_Manga_Pilot). Would the manga pilot be considered canon? And thus, would I be able to kill myself with the Death Note or not?

Comment: I can barely read it, also what exactly are you asking? I might upload a better quality picture but at the moment I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: 1. I am not sure what you mean by "can I kill myself (yourself) with the Death Note". 2. I have no idea what you mean by "does it count" because the info you have circled around in red makes no sense for anyone to even ask a question like does it count.

Comment: Are you asking if there is an inconsistency with this statement and [the idea that one can hypothetically commit suicide by writing one's own name down](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/7413/2604)?

Comment: I think the image has been taken from [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6015/1587), the OP is asking about the rule just above the bottom red box of the left. of cause this question has practically been answered in the link @Maroon posted

Comment: @アズーサ He is asking whether you can commit suicide with the Death Note, because it looks like you can in the original manga volumes, while in the picture (taken from the manga pilot) it clearly states you cannot do so. That's why he asked whether it would still count as canon.

Comment: @PeterRaeves- So that's what he's asking. I think I am ready to remove my close vote now.

Comment: @アズーサ I edited the question to (hopefully) make it more clear what OP was trying to ask. Also gave him +1, because personally this made me read the pilot, which I didn't know existed yet. Lets see what the rest of the community thinks about this.

Comment: @PeterRaeves- I approved your edit. The only thing I am worried about is that what the OP circled in the original is not circled in the new one but I think the edit is okay.

Comment: @アズーサ as i pointed out in my comment the image was most likely taken from the answer i linked to, what was circled was talking about the page limits of the death note while the OP was talking about the comment about writing one's name which is assumed from the question title and Madara's edit

Comment: quality and image dimensions matched too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned by [Maroon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2604/maroon), OP's question would possibly contradict the answer at  [Can a person shorten their own life by using the Death Note?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7412/can-a-person-shorten-his-her-own-life-by-using-the-note)

So before answering OP's question, lets first see what we know about the effect of writing your own name in the Death Note.

1. [In the manga pilot](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Note_Manga_Pilot), there is a rule that says:

   > You will not die if you write your own name in the Death Note, but it is not recommended.
2. [In the movie The Last Name](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Note:_The_Last_Name), we see L die from writing his own name in the Death Note:

   > Later it is revealed that L did not die and avoided death by writing his name in the notebook stating, "L Lawliet will die 23 days from this date".
   >
   > The film ends 23 days later, with L dying peacefully.
3. [In the one shot special](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Note_One-Shot_Special), we read that the C-killer dies from writing his own name:

   > This resulted in C-Kira writing his own name in the Death Note.

Looking at the available evidence, it would indeed seem like a possible contradiction (although Miura-kun was about to try and commit suicide in the manga pilot and there is no evidence he wouldn't have died). Therefore, in order to correctly reply to OP's question I checked what should be considered [canon according to the Death Note wiki](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Guide_to_Canon). Since the only three sources considered as canon are [the twelve original manga volumes](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Death_Note_Chapters), [Death Note 13: How to Read](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Note_13:_How_to_Read), and the [Death Note One-Shot-Special](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Note_One-Shot_Special), it would seem that **you can indeed commit suicide by using the Death Note** as seen in the One-Shot-Special, when the C-killer couldn't handle the pressure and committed suicide.

Comment: If you use Raye Penber's episode as a case study, you can write your own name down in someone else's Death Note and thereby kill yourself.

Comment: @Paul Rowe, Raye didnt write his own name though. Light did.

Comment: I was looking at it and, yes, Raye didn't write his own name down. I expect he could have and it would have worked, though...

Comment: @PaulRowe That's the thing. We all expect it to work, but as long as we don't have proof it does, it can't be considered as confirmed.

Comment: I think I write into the death note "I die by lich transformation."

Answer (score 0):

From Death Note 13: How to Read, How to Use V:

> A person can shorten his/her own life by using the note.

So, you may indeed shorten your own life.