# Would the Shinigami eye deal have shortened Light's lifespan?

Tags: death-note

We know, that if a human makes the Shinigami eye deal, he will lose half of his remaining lifespan. But, let's say Light made the shinigami deal. He might have killed L earlier, thus prolonging his life again. So here is my questions:

Would Light have lived longer, if he would have had the Shinigami eyes?

Comment: While I like the question, I voted for closure based on being primarily opinion-based. I don't think clear evidence could be provided for this question. Since I'm quite new to this moderating stuff, forgive me if I was wrong in doing so.

Comment: I don't agree that this is opinion based. Sure, it's *hypothetical*, but that isn't the same thing. Some hypothetical answers are nonetheless answerable with in-universe facts, e.g. http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11535/could-i-kill-myself-with-a-death-note. Others (perhaps like this one) have no in-universe answer. In the context of this site, the correct answer is simply to state that there's no way we can know for sure because it wasn't explained. Closing as opinion-based is for questions which are *actively seeking* opinions, not simply hypothetical ones.

Comment: @LoganM even with the information given on the manga there is no way to deduce a right answer out of this, what the OP proposes is already hypothetical, hence people will give him what they think that would happen and again the OP will pick the answer he likes the most or feels its the closest to his own opinion. There is no definitive information on the manga that would with 100% certain say Light would have his life prolonged or even shortened.

Comment: @Prix Read what I said again, I already addressed your complaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypothetically speaking(since that is what it means to give Light the shinigami eyes at an early stage), if you give Light the shinigami eyes, the early he could have killed L, was when they were frequenting the same school/university and at that point L was already highly suspicious of Light to the point of tracking him.

If L were to die there regardless of how, it would trigger L's successors to come in with all the already collected information which again would be focused towards Light with the prediction of not to expose yourself to Light.

There is the fact pointed that Light could not kill without knowing one's name based on L's experiment, but would that be suffice for them to cease investigations at such an early stage which not even L ceased him self?

Comment: The thing is Light put everything Mika did into play as the long con, which means he wouldn't have exposed himself like that to L if he had other cards to play.  Lets assume the eyes had no risk to his life. He would have definitely used it without using risky factors like Mika, Takada and Mikami where he was taking risks that they will react and move the way he had planned for them to. L only knew as much as he did about the death note due to his study of Mika.

Comment: @Quikstryke from the moment the Shinigami met Light he already knew his lifespan was short, that is probably why he offered the Eyes to make things more interesting. Unless Shinigami eye's cannot predict turn of events which I doubt.

Comment: There is no proof he knew his life span was short. Ryuk never alluded to this in the manga/anime so that would be speculation.  Also they cannot predict events which was the whole reason Ryuk did what he did as that was his entertainment.  He wanted to see how far light can go.  He also tells light he just randomly dropped the book, he didn't know who was going to pick it up.

Comment: @Quikstryke not Ryuk predicting future but the calculation of the lifespan and Light was pretty much identified before he could have facial information of L to assimilate with which at that point would be meaningless giving the successors available.

Comment: Light was identified as a potential suspect without any evidence.  When L first met him he was under the impression the only way he can die is if light had a name so for him to meet light then die right away when light according to L didnt know his name, would have proved that light was innocent in the eyes of the other investigators.  They would moved on in the investigation. Furthermore Light could kill by other means than a heart attack.  He could have ensured L got depressed or went insane before dieing casting doubt on the validity of his investigation.

Comment: @Quikstryke At the moment they met, his life course was already decided by L's successors regardless of him having the eyes or not. It would have only moved things fast forward as it was. The rational course to make L's not suspect of Light would have been for L to survive and not getting killed so he could move towards a new target as being the supposed Kira. We could argue this all day long if you don't provide any factual evidence that backup your ideas it will be as much as an assumption as mine and it will come down in the end to people's opinion of what they believe to be.

Comment: As mentioned his successors were only successful due to his actions, this was acknowledged by them.  They wouldn't have known about the notebook or Mika which are major factors for their win.

Comment: @Quikstryke and what makes you think they would not investigate L's death? What makes you think they would not come down to the same conclusion? What makes you think they could not re-investigate the case and get to the same culprit? You are overlooking a lot of facts and again not providing any factual evidence. Just because they do not know of the existence of the death note does not make it impossible for then to re-investigate the case. The exception here is that they would not do the same course of action L did as to bring the culprit under the same roof.

Comment: What facts are there for what you are saying? It is also conjecture.  The facts are the evidence that was already collected by L.  If L died early, then whether they have the ability to recollect those facts are up in the air, but it was established L was a better detective than Near and Mello and Light beat L.

Comment: @Quikstryke facts, you can post manga images or anything that refutes the information I've provided until then it seems to be those are 2 opinion-based answers with baseless grounds.

Comment: The page is going to a pain to find will post later with it if you still need it unless someone else can weigh in.  It also explicitly states it in the wikia (under plot). http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Near

Comment: @Quikstryke also the earliest he could have killed L was when L already had high suspects of him and were sharing the same University or w/e, if he were to die there, that information would have been passed down to L's successors as well. That would most likely keep tracking of what he does without Light knowing there was a successors taking place. Don't forget we are talking about an hypothetical event of L dying early and all my facts are going towards that, against the early events of the manga, Misa was not yet met and one would the successors would come in.

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming Light had a long life ahead of him (no health issues) the answer is an obvious yes knowing the chain of events we know.

You're probably asking if Near/Mello would have caught him anyway, but it was already established Near only won due to the combined help he got from L's investigation and Mello's actions. Light was the better intellect (plus in your scenario he has his eyes).

But of course no way for Light to know this and he assumed he can beat anything that gets thrown at him.  Probably rightfully so, as the Mikami zealousness/sloppiness caused the downfall at the end, not Light's plan.